# Write expressions using only NAND operator and prove logically equivalent?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus

It can be shown that ~$p \equiv (p \uparrow p)$
and $p \wedge q \equiv (p \uparrow q) \uparrow (p \uparrow q)$. You don’t need to show these. However, write the expressions $p \to q$ and $p \vee q$ using only the nand operator $\uparrow$ and show that they are equivalent via truth table.

A bit confused about this question, I understand truth tables and proving equivalent but I don't understand how to rewrite $p \to q$ and $p \vee q$ using only nand.

Thank you for your help

Comment: You have only to use the equiv of $p \to q$ with $\lnot (p \land \lnot q)$ and similar for $\lor$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. Following the suggestion of Mauro Allegranza, first rewrite $p \to q$ as $\neg p \vee q$. Besides, you should know that $p \uparrow q = \neg p \vee \neg q$. Which transformation do you need to pass from $\neg p \vee \neg q$ to $\neg p \vee q$? For the final touch, use the fact that $\neg p = p \uparrow p$. For the second exercise, same idea with $\neg p \vee q$ and $p \vee q$.

Answer (score 1):

Just complete the table using the equivalences you say that you know (deMorgan's and conditional equivalence).

$$\def\nand{\mathop\uparrow}\bbox[2ex,border:solid 1pt lemonchiffon]{\begin{array}{lll} p\nand q &\equiv & \neg(p\wedge q) & \equiv & p\nand q & \text{(definition)}\\ \neg p &\equiv& \neg(p\wedge p)&\equiv& p\nand p \\p\wedge q &\equiv& \neg\neg(p\wedge q) &\equiv& (p\nand q)\nand(p\nand q) \\ p\vee q &\equiv& \phantom{\neg(\neg p\wedge\neg q)} &\equiv& \phantom{(p\nand p)\nand(q\nand q)} \\ p\to q &\equiv&\phantom{\neg p\vee q}&\equiv& \phantom{p\nand(q\nand q)} \end{array}}$$